# when checkbox is checked then select will show

Tags: jquery, select, checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" name="seeds-a1" value="Indigofera" /> <span>Indigofera</span>

//this select will show if checkbox mark as checked 

<select class="selectDrop" name="orders">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option>1/2 kg</option>
  <option>1 kg</option>
  <option>2 kg</option>
  <option>3 kg</option>
  <option>4 kg</option>
  <option>5 kg</option>
</select>

<input type="checkbox" name="seeds-a2" value="calliandra" /> <span>calliandra</span>

    //this select will show if checkbox mark as checked 

    <select class="selectDrop" name="orders2">
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <option>1/2 kg</option>
      <option>1 kg</option>
      <option>2 kg</option>
      <option>3 kg</option>
      <option>4 kg</option>
      <option>5 kg</option>
    </select>

   <input type="checkbox" name="seeds-a3" value="ipil-ipil" /> <span>ipil-ipil</span>

    //this select will show if checkbox mark as checked 

    <select class="selectDrop" name="orders3">
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <option>1/2 kg</option>
      <option>1 kg</option>
      <option>2 kg</option>
      <option>3 kg</option>
      <option>4 kg</option>
      <option>5 kg</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [`.toggle(switch)`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-showOrHide) inside the checkbox's [`change`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event,

```
$('[type="checkbox"][name="seeds-a1"]').change(function(){
  $('select.selectDrop').toggle(this.checked);
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LfS2u/)

Based on your new requirement, you should use,

```
$('[type="checkbox"][name^="seeds-"]').change(function(){
  $(this).nextAll('select.selectDrop').first().toggle(this.checked);
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LfS2u/1/)

Comment: by the way i have a list of checkbox how to make it work

Comment: is that posible when the select is hide the value of select turn to defaul?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55353/discussion-between-jhunlio-and-rajaprabhu-aravindasamy).

Comment: @jhunlio Sorry man, In my office links to the chatting sites are banned.. :( Really sorry. But you can ask this as a new question so that you can get more expert's eye on that. And please link me to that question if you wish.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.toggle()` along with checked property of checkbox:

```
$('[name="seeds-a1"]').change(function () {
   $("select.selectDrop").toggle(this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
  $('select.selectDrop').toggle(this.checked);
});

});
```